# Showing System.Web.Helpers.Chart in a partial view from the model

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, charts

So I was trying out the Chart helpers in the System.Web.Helpers namespace.

according to http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/data/7-displaying-data-in-a-chart

I make the chart in a .cshtml view but I wanted to keep it in the ViewModel instead.

No problem except for when I'm trying to render it as a smaller image in the website.

I thought the cleanest solution would be to create one shared partial view to render graphs from models

_graph.cshtml

```
@model System.Web.Helpers.Chart

@Model.Write()
```

And then render this partial view somehow in the proper websites. I tried a few versions but can't seem to get it to work.

Website.cshtml

```
<div>
    <h2>Some header above a graph</h2>
    <img src="@Html.Partial("_graph", Model.TheChart)" />
</div>
```

This doesn't work and I'm not certain how to do this. Only think I can think of now is making all models with charts inherit an Interface that exposes Chart and let that be the model for _graph.cshtml.

```
<img src="_graph.cshtml" />
```

But not sure if the this uses the Model.

Any opinions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
<div>
    <h2>Some header above a graph</h2>
    <img src="@Url.Action("DrawChart")" />
</div>
```

and then you could have a controller action:

```
public ActionResult DrawChart()
{
    MyViewModel model = ...
    return View(model);
}
```

and a corresponding view that will draw the chart (`DrawChart.cshtml`):

```
@model MyViewModel

@{
    // TODO: use the data from the model to draw a chart

    var myChart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400)
        .AddTitle("Chart Title")
        .AddSeries(
            name: "Employee",
            xValue: new[] {  "Peter", "Andrew", "Julie", "Mary", "Dave" },
            yValues: new[] { "2", "6", "4", "5", "3" })
        .Write();
}
```

and the rendered result:

---

[image]

Comment: Yeah but I'm looking for a way so that I can create the chart in the viewmodel or a seperate class and not in the cshtml. Is there any performance reason for keeping it in a cshtml?

Comment: @IngóVals, you don't need to use a .CSHTML if you don't want to. You could do the rendering in the controller action directly. I could update my answer if you are interested in this solution. But in all cases in your main view you should use an `<img>` tag pointing to a server side action that is responsible for generating the chart. Whether you use a view or not is up to you to decide. The advantage of using a view is a clearer separation between the controller and the presentation, but as I said it is perfectly possible to generate the chart directly in the controller.

Comment: Ok I just returned the image from the Method in the controller and it worked fine thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
<h2>Some header above a graph</h2>
<img src="@Url.Action("DrawChart")" />
</div>

public ActionResult DrawChart()
{
MyViewModel model = ...
return View(model);  

}
```

!!! To send the Model parameter to DrawChart

Change to

```
<div>
    <h2>Some header above a graph</h2>
    <img src="@Url.Action("DrawChart",Model)" />
</div>

public ActionResult DrawChart(MyViewModel _MyViewModel )
{
    MyViewModel model = MyViewModel ;
    return View(model);
}
```

MyViewModel is Null

Seek advice from those who know.

Comment: MVC can't map complex types. So you either have to use simple types to send the model properties separate or use Ajax.