# Displaying a chart in a view with razor

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, charts

I have a web application and i need to add a chart in my view :

```
   @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Travail";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/Template.cshtml";

}

    @using System.Web.Helpers;
    @section logout {
        <a href='@Url.Action("Retour", "Client")'><img src="~/Content/images/home-icon.png" /></a>
        <a href='@Url.Action("Logout", "Home")' style="margin-left: 91.6%"><img src="~/Content/images/images.jpg" style="width:37px; height:37px" /></a>
        }
    @{
        var ar = new Planning.Models.Arbre();
        var dataView = ar.Get_List_Tache();
        List<string> descr = new List<string>();
        List<int> avance = new List<int>();
        foreach( Planning.Models.Tache tac in dataView){
            descr.Add(tac.Tache_description);
            avance.Add(tac.Avancement);
       }
        Chart chartXml;
        var filePathName = "_ChartFiles/XmlChart.xml";
        if (File.Exists(Server.MapPath(filePathName)))
        {
            chartXml = new Chart(width: 200,
                                 height: 200);
        } 
        else{
        chartXml = new Chart(width: 200,
                                 height: 200);
        chartXml.AddTitle("Avancement de taches");
        chartXml.AddSeries(
            name: "Les taches",
            axisLabel: "Les taches",
            xValue: descr,
            yValues: avance);
        chartXml.SaveXml(path: filePathName);}


        }
    <div>@chartXml.Write()</div>
```

[image: capture]
how can i display the chart in this view?Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [`Chart.Write`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.chart.write.aspx)

```
<div>@myChart.Write()</div>
```

See also: [Showing System.Web.Helpers.Chart in a partial view from the model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9685302/showing-system-web-helpers-chart-in-a-partial-view-from-the-model)

Comment: please see my edit . the problem now is that the template isn't displayed only the chart is here