# MVC Charts - Passing data from one view to another cshtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc, charts

Working within an existing MVC app I am creating various charts to display client data. I'm entirely new to Charts in ASP.NET. I'm primarily using http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/data/7-displaying-data-in-a-chart as a resource for creating the charts.

Currently I am creating the charts fine, and typically my x values are fixed (e.g. Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr etc.) and my y values are found by querying a list that is sent to the view.

The chart objects I'm creating however create an image, which is then the only thing displayed on the page, and my Layout is lost as a result obviously.

The article mentions embedding in a web page by calling the chart from a separate view as an  like:

```
  <body>
    <p><img src="ChartArrayBasic.cshtml" /> </p>
  </body>
```

As I am generating my charts by querying a list in the view for the variable values, in order to make them more general chart views that can be used by all clients for their own data, I need the .cshtml file I call to receive a List.

Is it possible to: 
1. Call the view from the action method.
2. The view displays a regular page with another view embedded in it.
3. the embedded view needs to receive a List object from the initial view.

Thanks,
JK

Comment: Create a `ChildOnlyAction` that returns a partial view of the the chart, then render it in the view using `@Html.Action()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@JonnyKnottsvill You basically do what was [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9685441/1565402) with the exception, as advised above, to create a **PartialView** so that you can reuse it later as you want.

`_ChartParialView.cshtml` in **Shared** folder inside **Views**:

```
@model IEnumerable<string>

@{
    var myChart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400)
        .AddTitle("Chart Title")
        .AddSeries(
            name: "Employee",
            xValue: new[] { "Peter", "Andrew", "Julie", "Mary", "Dave" },
            yValues: Model)
        .Write();
}
```

The controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult DrawChart()
    {
        var model = new[] { "2", "6", "4", "5", "3" };

        return PartialView("_ChartPartialView", model);
    }
}
```

The Home(Index) View where you want the chart to be rendered as image:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Chart";
}

<h2>Chart</h2>

<img src="@Url.Action("DrawChart")" />
```